# WebAPI 2.0 custom media type formatter controller method never called on POST request

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following `Product`, `CustomJsonMediaFormatter` and `ProductsController` classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class CustomJsonMediaFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{

    public CustomJsonMediaFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Product))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Type enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<Product>);
            return enumerableType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Product))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Type enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<Product>);
            return enumerableType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent        content)
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(jw, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content,    IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(readStream))
        {
            using (var jw = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize(jw);
            }
        }
    }
}



public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult AddProduct([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        products.Add(product);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The WebAPI setup looks like this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new CustomJsonMediaFormatter());

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**The problem:**
The HTTP request `GET http://localhost:47503/api/products/1` works correctly. The `CanWriteType(...)` and `WriteToStream(...)` methods are called correctly and I get a JSON Product on the other end. Getting all products (`GET http://localhost:47503/api/products`) also works as expected.

However, `POST http://localhost:47503/api/products` with the body `{"Id":10,"Name":"Apple","Category":"Groceries","Price":5.0}` does not work. The `CanReadType(...)` and `ReadFromStream(...)` methods are called correctly. An object of type `Product` is correctly produced in the `ReadFromStream(...)` method, but the `AddProduct(...)` method in the controller is never called. Then the `CanWriteType(...)` method is called with type = `System.Web.Http.HttpError`.

If I make the exact same request with the default JSON formatter it works fine.

The content-type is "application/json" in all cases.

Thanks,
Iulian

Comment: How does the routing know to call the `AddProduct` action?

Comment: Actions are selected like this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection. If I add the `[ActionName("xyz")]` attribute to the `AddProduct` method and make the request `POST http://localhost:47503/api/products/xyz` the same thing happens. Same if I add a `Route` attribute. Matching the controller action does not seem to be the problem. Also, changing the formatter to the default one makes everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The routing must be told which method to use for the POST request. Either the method should be named `Post` or you should add  the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Product product)
{
    products.Add(product);
    return Ok();
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddProduct([FromBody] Product product)
{
    products.Add(product);
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer doesn't produce a Product object, so casting the deserialization result to Product will produce an error. You can use Deserialize to deserialize to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the Type in Deserialize method. Like this:

```
   using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(readStream))
   {
      var text = sw.ReadToEnd();
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, type);
   }
```